# Is there a way to export/share "favourite" gallery images?

Tags: photos, gallery

I have selected a few hundred images as "favourite" in the stock Galaxy S3 Photo Gallery app. I can view these photos by tapping on the "Albums" drop down and choosing "Favourites". Once in this view I can open individual images or start a slideshow. There is no multi-select option like in "albums" view which allows for bulk sharing of images.

Does anybody know a novel way to export/share *all* favourite images?

I have tried other gallery apps in the hope they shared the "favourite" database but each has their own. AirDroid also does not have a "show favourites" option.

Or does anybody know if the list of favourite images can be exported from some sqlite database and I can script out the file names for copying?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried an alternative gallery app? One of those might offer that feature.

Comment: @Izzy I'm also trying to copy just the favorite images to my PC. Izzy, if you know one, could you please recommend a gallery app that does that? or at least anything similar?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is, but I don't know which of the thousands does that. But phrased correctly, that would be a perfect case for [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Photos app instead (it [no longer requires a Google+ profile](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6142214?hl=en)) which has the option you are looking for [in the latest 2018 version](https://www.theverge.com/platform/amp/2018/5/21/17377738/google-photos-favorites-new-feature). But you cannot export or migrate your favorites out of Gallery and the Gallery app is [removed by Lollipop](http://www.androidcentral.com/where-did-gallery-go-after-lollipop-update).

Comment: The gallery app is deprecated in AOSP Android 5. The question is about the gallery app in [touchwiz](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-touchwiz), which will probably still exist in the Android 5 version of Touchwiz because manufacturers don't like to remove functionality, and they already had a custom gallery app that was different than the one in Stock AOSP Android.

Answer (score 1):

Tap a photo so that the thumbnail views appear at the bottom. Then long press on one of the thumbnails and you then get an option to select all

Additional Hint: "Select all" you will find in the upper option bar where you usually choose your album "Favorites". Use the Share-Button and one of the given options to save the files to another folder (e.g. use "ES Explorer Save as"-Option).

Answer (score 1):

I'm from 2017. Here 3 years into the future the Gallery App does support the option to "share" favourite photos, by selection and hitting the share option in the menu above.

HOWEVER, in the case you want to "save" these to a local folder of their own you're are screwed. Sure you can "share" them over WiFi through the social media apps, but simply transfer/move them locally into an organised folder - no chance - thanks Gallery. Cutting edge stuff! It cannot be hard to add this option here. I mean the option exists outside of favourites, so why not inside. Makes life painful and no sense!

Finally found a solution though thanks to @greenux 's contribution above! With the ES Explorer File Manager App installed you can save the Favourites locally through ES Explorer using the "share". Gallery should provide this natively.

Comment: Vendor lock.in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick :

1. Create a New Folder in the Gallery
2. Click on Add photo icon "+"
3. In the options you can see Favorites Folder
4. Select the pictures you want to export and then select Copy/Move option.
5. Done :-)